# CoreData concurrency debugging and NSManagedObject primitiveValueForKey:

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I've enabled `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` in my app. Most of the crashes are simple to resolve with correct use of `performBlock(andWait):`.

However, I'm also sometimes getting crashes when accessing properties on managed objects. This crash is different than the usual `__Multithreading_Violation_AllThatIsLeftToUsIsHonor__`.

Instead this is a crash inside `NSManagedObect primitiveValueForKey:` on `_PFAssertSafeMultiThreadedAccess_impl`:

```
0x10626d48e <+190>: movq   0x2b2bbb(%rip), %rsi      ; "managedObjectContext"
0x10626d495 <+197>: movq   %rbx, %rdi
0x10626d498 <+200>: callq  *0x25bd2a(%rip)           ; (void *)0x000000010602a000: objc_msgSend
0x10626d49e <+206>: movq   0x2b4683(%rip), %rsi      ; "primitiveValueForKey:"
0x10626d4a5 <+213>: movq   %rax, %rdi
0x10626d4a8 <+216>: callq  0x106303270               ; _PFAssertSafeMultiThreadedAccess_impl
0x10626d4ad <+221>: jmp    0x10626d3f1               ; <+33>
0x10626d4b2 <+226>: movq   0x2b25cf(%rip), %rsi      ; "retain"
0x10626d4b9 <+233>: movq   0x25bd08(%rip), %r12      ; (void *)0x000000010602a000: objc_msgSend
```

Has anyone encountered this also? It feels like a bug in Apple's code to me, `primitiveValueForKey:` should be responsible for using the NSManagedObjectContext correctly.

Comment: Marcus is right (of course :D) and I add this to his answer: use objectID's instead of passing the managed object between threads. That's the safe way to access an object between threads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a bug in Apple's code.  You cannot access a `NSManagedObject` from any thread other than the one that it was created on.  If you do so you are violating the thread containment rules.

This crash is exactly that.  You are touching a `NSManagedObject` from a thread other than the one that created it.